# Graphic errors for ATI RS600M

Tags: drivers, graphics, ati, radeon

I wanted to give my old *Samsung P200-PRO T8100 Bordoso* a last change.

It has the ATI RS600M chipset (Radeon Xpress 1250 graphics card). After installing Ubuntu 14.04, the navigation on the top has a strange graphic error, which is also on the screenshot:

[image: Graphic errors for ATI RS600M]

The installed driver, related to `lshw`, is `radeon`. This driver [fully supports](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RadeonDriver) my chipset for Ubuntu 14.04.

What could cause the problem?

Comment: Please try installing the prorietary fglrx driver in the *Additional drivers* tab in the *Software & Updates* utility, if it is listed there and reboot your computer.

Comment: "No additional drivers available", so it is not available

Comment: May it be a temporary issue? Does it go away when you hit Alt+F2 and execute `unity --replace`?

Comment: it doesnt help.

Comment: I tried `fglrx` manually. `sudo aticonfig --initial` gives me a `No supported adapters detected`

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. Found a "solution".

1. `sudo apt-get install unity-tweak-tool`
2. Open the Unity Tweak Tool either from launcher or command line
3. Select "Panel" from the menu
4. Slide the "Transparency level" slider all the way to the right
5. Close the tool and enjoy having no more lines :-)